# ASP Web Forms show error for users without needed role

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, web-config

I'm using standard Web Forms authentication and trying to make a certain part of the website restricted for regular users. When user enters /admin_panel* they should get an error like 403 or 404, but with my config user gets redirected to login page instead, even though he is already authenticated.

Piece of my config:

```
<location path="admin_panel">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*, ?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: That's not how this works. Users won't get a 404 because they lack permissions to something. They will be redirected to login because they lack the credentials necessary. Being logged in or not doesn't come into play, only that they need to be authenticated and they need a specific role.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick yes, I see that this doesn't work like that. What can I do to make it work like that? 

Of course I can check permissions on every page and throw 404, if the user is authenticated without specific role, but it seems wrong.